# USB male android to audio output

Tags: usb, speakers, android

I was curious if I could possibly strip the end of a USB cable, and direct audio traffic from the phone through the USB to a 5volt in p/n speaker, sub, or a tweeter. I haven't seen this done anywhere else online and I'm just curious if I could direct the audio out of the USB female port, vs using auxillery, considering I'm trying to make portable speakers, the auxillery output is just a wee too weak, and I can't always bring an amp with me wherever I go.

Comment: USB is a purely digital interface. You can stream digital audio through it, but to drive speakers you need to decode the digital audio and convert it to analog audio. It's not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. Most phones do not have audio over usb. Some do,  but it's rare. My phone, a Samsung Avant, has a dock cable that allows usb charging and audio and video out over USB.

It would be more likely that your phone supports USB OTG. It would allow you to use a usb audio card, and provide five volt out as allowed by your phone. All you need is a usb OTG adapter. Or there is many usb OTG sound cards already available, with a male usb micro connector. Same as usb OTG headphones.